# Noticias relacionadas no site

Tags: html, css, html5, layout

olá gostaria de saber como eu faço para colocar noticias relacionadas no meu site 
tipo eu tenho uma sessão no meu site chamada "NOTICIAS DA POLITICA". 
e a pessoa ao clikar na noticia aparecer outras noticias sobre politica abaixo?
tipo:uma < section > ou< article >"veja mais"
e aparece mais noticias relacionadas ?

Comment: Sua pergunta está pouco específica. Poderia detalhar para ajudar a comunidade a respondê-la?

Comment: me ajude ai por favor

Comment: A solução que você quer é diferente da resposta do @julio-henrique? Especifique.

Comment: nao tem uma maneira de fazer com html e css nao ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Danilo, agora entendi o que você quer. Você pode usar as classes de css e verificar o evento desejado. Pode ser antes (:before) ou depois (:after). Também, como o exemplo abaixo, usar o evento de foco (:focus).

Verifique o exemplo abaixo que achei em uma breve pesquisa no SOen. Perceba que ele usou somente html e css como era de sua vontade.

> Hide Show content-list with only CSS, no javascript used
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732348/2788478

Comment: muito obrigado por tudo ! vou dar uma olhada aki valew

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma `div` invisível que seja aberta quando `clickar` em `read more..`

```js
function myFunction(){

  document.getElementById('divNoticia').style.display = 'block';
  
}
```

```html
Homem é pego fazer pergunta no site StackOverFlow <a id='readmore' href="#" onclick='myFunction()'>leia mais...</a>

<div id='divNoticia' style='display:none;'>
  <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*y48w0QXSXaByvUuQTNloQQ.png" width='200'>
  <p>Como fazer um crud em PHP? tenho esse código já e esta dando erro na linha 5 alguem pode me ajudar?</p>
</div>
```